# Restoring Wordpress posts from database only

Tags: database, mysql, hosting

I paid *1and1* my payment, but even after showing payment proof they deleted my entire account, domain and all. I only have my Database left (long ago I took a database backup using phpMyAdmin).

Can I get my posts back from it?

Comment: Next time, i suggest you to try and find a better service provider. This happened to me too, a long time ago.

Comment: When I first started playing with web development about a decade ago, 1and1 was actually my first web-host and domain registrar. At the time, they had a lot of bizarre restrictions, their backup system failed me more than once, and I always had a difficult time wrestling with their support... when I finally decided to leave, it took more than a month to get back control over some 5 or 6 domains. I believe I straight up lost one due to some ridiculous clause which made it nontransferable. I've experienced some hiccups with different hosts since then, but none of them even compare

Comment: I was hurt by 1and1 as well.  That being said, I think we all know (and any who read in the future should be aware) it's better to MAKE sure you have your own backups and check up on them.  It's NOT just the providers fault.

Comment: Do you have full backup from cpanel? If you have one, import your database file sql to your phpmyadmin sql

Answer (score 8):

Re-install a new copy of wordpress and then put in the credentials to your database in the new install.

If you install wordpress and try to load the domain with no database attached, it will start the site creation wizard.  Just enter the correct database credentials (username, database name, password, and location) and it will load for you instead of initializing a database.

If you only have the sql, you'll need to create a new database and import the sql file into this database. the easiest way of doing that is creating the database, then in mysqladmin importing the database. (import in top row of php myadmin once you've selected the database on the left.)

The site won't look good, but when you log into your dashboard, all posts will be there.

From there you can either export the posts (tools/export) or use this database and add a new theme.  Photos will not be recovered for pages or posts though